# How to save best models in latest Tensorflow Object Detection API V2 with TF2?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

Recently I am trying Tensorflow Object Detection API V2 with TF2, and I've sucessfully trained a network.

However, I found little information about how to save the best model.

I've found some simple tutorials that don't talk much about these details.

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685923/how-to-store-best-models-checkpoints-not-only-newest-5-in-tensorflow-object-de), however the best answer is to modify `legacy/trainer.py`, which seems to be outdated.

I've also found another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005432/is-there-some-way-to-save-best-model-only-with-tensorflow-estimator-train-and-ev), however the answers are talking about `exporters`, which is in `model_lib.py`, but I can't find similar parameter in `model_lib_v2.py`

**So, for V2, which file should I modify to save the best model?**

Comment: I am looking for exactly the same, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the official scripts from [TF2 Object Detection repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), there is a `tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py` file for saving models.

**Usage**:

```
python .\exporter_main_v2.py \
    --input_type image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path .\...\pipeline.config \
    --trained_checkpoint_dir .\...\training \
    --output_directory .\...\my_model
```

Source: **https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-model**